# Фразеология

Tags: фразеология

Можно ли сказать выскажите свои точки зрения?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: выскажите свою точку зрения.

Изначально это термин, сравнимый по значению со словом "аспект (от лат. aspectus — вид). С определенной точки зрения (с определенного места) рассматривался предмет или явление.

Затем слово приобретает переносное значение.  Точка зрения - это понятие о предмете с определенной стороны или сторона предмета, изучаемого определенной наукой: философский А., экономический А. и пр.

В обычной жизни по определенной проблеме мы также высказываем точку зрения. Хотя  наше мнение может включать ряд суждений по данной теме, но все они доказывают одну определенную мысль.

Answer (score 1):

Странный вопрос.

Если говорящий обращается к многочисленной аудитории, то только так и можно сказать.
Вероятность того, что все присутствующие воспринимают проблему совершенно одинаково, в современном обществе невелика.

Наличие нескольких точек зрения на вопрос у одного индивида, вероятно, можно расценивать как один из симптомов шизофрении.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы и нет? Ведь если диалог происходит более, чем с одним собеседником, то и точек зрения априори может быть несколько.